# Cannot switch to NVIDIA GPU despite downloading proprietary driver (Acer) in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, nvidia-prime

Despite having downloaded drivers described in other tutorials for switching to dedicated Nvidia GPUs on Ubuntu, system details still show Intel being used.

#### Details

Using a machine with hybrid graphics, currently system shows that Intel GPU is being used.

[image]

Following several tutorials on switching to a separate nvidia gpu, I did the following:

- Run command to see what gpus were available and what drivers they should be using:

  ```
  $ lspci -k | grep -A 2 -i "VGA"
  00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 591b (rev 04)
  Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device 118a
  Kernel driver in use: i915

  01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1c20 (rev a1)
  Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device 118b
  Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_384_drm, nvidia_384
  ```
- Go to `software and updates` menu and switch to nvidia proprietary driver and apply changes:
  [image]
- Restart the system
- Run command

  ```
  $ nvidia-detector
  none
  ```

*

```
    $ nvidia-smi
    zsh: command not found: nvidia-smi
```

- Check the nvidia control center

  ```
  $ nvidia-settings
  ERROR: Error querying enabled displays on GPU 0 (Missing Extension).
  ERROR: Error querying connected displays on GPU 0 (Missing Extension).

  ** Message: PRIME: No offloading required. Abort
  ** Message: PRIME: is it supported? no

  ERROR: nvidia-settings could not find the registry key file. This file should have been
         installed along with this driver at
         /usr/share/nvidia/nvidia-application-profiles-key-documentation. The application
         profiles will continue to work, but values cannot be prepopulated or validated,
         and will not be listed in the help text. Please see the README for possible values 
         and descriptions.
  ```

[image]
Notice, no GPU is listed.

As shown, a lot of commands are not giving the expected outputs, yet I installed the driver, so don't know what the problem here is?

#### Note

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 dual booted on a Windows 10 machine (Acer Helios 300 laptop) installed via a live USB using the *Install Ubuntu alongside Windows* option (on a separate SSD put in specifically for the purpose of dual booting Linux).

Comment: Checkout `ubuntu-drivers` command (`-h` to see how to).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I fixed the problem:

1. Restart the computer and press F12 during boot.
2. Disable secure boot: In the boot menu, go to the `security` tab and set a supervisor password (**remember/store this password**) (cant disable secure boot without setting a password here for Acer's). Then go to the `boot` tab and disable secure boot. Exit with changes saved and reboot to ubuntu (I **think** you can later re-enable secure boot after (re)installing the driver in later steps) ([link to where I got this specific info for Acer computers](https://itsfoss.com/disable-secure-boot-in-acer/))
3. Run: `sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-*` (`sudo apt pruge nvidia-*` should also work too). (Note I was initially using ohmyzsh and it was not detecting the wildcard (*) operator, switch shell to `bash` to run this commnad)
4. Use the `Additional Drivers` app to switch back to the proprietary nvidia driver as shown in the original question (since after removing the nvidia packages in step-2, the driver should be back to the opensource one) and apply changes to reinstall the driver.
5. Restart the system. Try running `nvidia-smi` and looking for PRIME profiles in `nvidia-settings` to see if this worked.
6. **Optionally**: re-enable secure boot and clear the supervisor password (though I did not do this myself, since other apps seems to have problems when secure boot is enabled (eg. virtualbox))

I realize this is arguably a dup. of similar questions and answers for this common gpu problem, but leaving it here just because it provides a full set of problem steps and resolution (as well as some Acer machine specific info).

**Note:** I probably should have done step 2 then 1, but just writing the true order that I specifically did things for the sake of truthful documentation of what I did.

Comment: No luck usind live usb ubuntu 19.10

Answer (score 0):

ummm, go into MB bios and change IGP to PEG and make sure video is attached to GPU in the first PCIE slot.